# Manually ziplalign-ing android unsigned APK exported from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, android-keystore, zipalign

Is the APK obtained by clicking "Open Folder" (hence unsigned APK) under Build/ViewArchives in Xamarin already zipaligned?

And if it is, can I cause any problems with the package if I manually zipaligned it again and then manually signed it using a *.jks keystore file in command prompt before uploading to Google Play Store?

Comment: Yes you should be fine to [manually sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk) your unsigned apk with `apksigner`.

Comment: Thanks @JonDouglas I appreciate it